# Animately increase content size

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application of iphone,I added a view dynamically to a UIScrollview and increase the content size of scroll view on a button press.Now i need to animate this process of content size change .Is there any way to animate the increase of content size

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the resizing of a UIView like this:

```
view.frame = [self whateverYourInitialFrameIs];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizingAnimation" context:nil];
view.frame = [self whateverYourNewFrameShouldBe];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Read the documentation for the methods listed under "Animating Views" in the UIView API reference.